# Express v4 router as class

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

The app compiles without errors, and says that the server starts on the correct port. However when I go to any of my registered routes, I get a cannot access this route error.

I haven't found much information on express with classes, especially the router part. From the `console.log(controller.router)` of the router variable it seems to be correct, the path missing it weird but I assume the regex just takes the place instead.

There also isn't a path method on the `this.router` instance so I'm not sure how else to path the path other than `get(path, handler)`.

```
console.log(`/v1${controller.basePath}`, controller.router):

""""
/v1/users [Function: router] {
  params: {},
  _params: [],
  caseSensitive: undefined,
  mergeParams: undefined,
  strict: undefined,
  stack: [
    Layer {
      handle: [Function: bound dispatch],
      name: 'bound dispatch',
      params: undefined,
      path: undefined,
      keys: [],
      regexp: /^\/users\/?$/i,
      route: [Route]
    },
    Layer {
      handle: [Function: bound dispatch],
      name: 'bound dispatch',
      params: undefined,
      path: undefined,
      keys: [],
      regexp: /^\/users\/?$/i,
      route: [Route]
    },
    Layer {
      handle: [Function: bound dispatch],
      name: 'bound dispatch',
      params: undefined,
      path: undefined,
      keys: [Array],
      regexp: /^\/users\/(?:([^\/]+?))\/?$/i,
      route: [Route]
    },
    Layer {
      handle: [Function: bound dispatch],
      name: 'bound dispatch',
      params: undefined,
      path: undefined,
      keys: [Array],
      regexp: /^\/users\/(?:([^\/]+?))\/?$/i,
      route: [Route]
    }
  ]
}
"""
```

I have also tried with `localhost:1337/v1/users/` just incase but same thing happens.

I'm lost as to what could be wrong, thanks for the help in advance!

App Class

```
import * as express from "express"
import * as mongoose from "mongoose"
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser"

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/socketpro", {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
})

class App {
    public port: number
    public app: express.Application

    private controllers: any

    constructor(controllers: any, port: number) {
        this.port = port
        this.controllers = controllers
        this.app = express()

        this.initializeMiddlewares()
        this.initializeControllers()
    }

    private initializeMiddlewares() {
        this.app.use(bodyParser.json())
    }

    private initializeControllers() {
        this.controllers.forEach((controller: any) => {
            console.log(`/v1${controller.basePath}`, controller.router)
            this.app.use(`/v1${controller.basePath}`, controller.router)
        })
    }

    public listen() {
        this.app.listen(this.port, () => {
            console.log(`App listening on the port ${this.port}`)
        })
    }
}

export default App
```

User Controller

```
import { UserModel as User, UserInterface } from "../Utils/User"
import { Router, Request, Response } from "express"

export default class UsersController {
    [x: string]: any

    public basePath = "/users"
    public router: Router = null

    private posts: UserInterface[] = []

    constructor() {
        this.router = Router()
        this.intializeRoutes()
    }

    public intializeRoutes() {
        let routes = [
            {
                path: "/",
                method: "get",
                function: "GetUsers",
            },
            {
                path: "/",
                method: "post",
                function: "CreateUser",
            },
            {
                path: "/:id",
                method: "get",
                function: "GetUser",
            },
            {
                path: "/:id",
                method: "post",
                function: "UpdateUser",
            },
        ]

        routes.map((route) => {
            let path = `${this.basePath}${route.path ?? ""}`

            switch (route.method) {
                case "get":
                    this.router.get(path, this[route.function])
                    break
                case "post":
                    this.router.post(path, this[route.function])
                    break
            }
        })
    }

    async GetUser(request: Request, response: Response) {
        let userId: string = request.params.id

        let user = await User.findOne({
            _id: userId,
        })

        response.send({
            user,
        })
    }

    async GetUsers(request: Request, response: Response) {
        response.send({status: true})
    }

    async CreateUser(request: Request, response: Response) {
        let user: UserInterface = new User(request.body)

        user = await user.save()

        response.send(user)
    }

    async UpdateUser(request: Request, response: Response) {
        let body: UserInterface = request.body

        await User.updateOne(
            {
                _id: request.params.id,
            },
            body
        ).exec()

        response.send({
            status: true,
        })
    }
}
```

Repo of the code: https://github.com/Rusherz/express-router-class

[Chrome URL showing: localhost:1337/v1/users and the error: Cannot GET /v1/users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWLta.png)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Can you show us your code and describe a particular problem with your code?  Code necessary to understand a question MUST be pasted into the question itself and NOT only available as an external link.  Those are stackoverflow guidelines and there are a whole bunch of good reasons for requiring questions to be written that way.  Please include the relevant code for the question IN the question itself, formatted appropriately as code.  You can leave an external link to the rest of the repository, but that must not be the only reference to the code.

Comment: I've updated the question, please let me know if it is more clear. Sorry about the code as well, it seemed better just giving the entire code base because I'm not entire use were the actual issue lies. But I added what the relevant code I believe to be.

Comment: You create a Router object and add routes to it, but where to you do `app.use(path, router)` with the router object to actually hook the router into your server?

Comment: FYI, specifying route function names by string in your table is a bit odd.  Why not just directly reference the methods themselves?

Comment: An observation.  You've created your own abstraction for many things that Express does and in the process made it very difficult for someone familiar with Express to understand your code.  I'm not sure you're making anything easier here while just creating your own internal API that nobody else will recognize.  You could use the express interface and extend it rather than hide/replace it to add your own capabilities (if something is missing) and then it wouldn't seem foreign to an Express developer.

Comment: Thats good to know, I was just interested in using a class type structure for the routes. I saw some documentation on experimental props but wasn't able to follow it/find it again. But it seems like I should just go back to the set up that works for sure, should I close the question?

Edit: typo

Answer (score 0):

The issue with my code was scoping, or what I believe to be scoping.

I found the post I was basing this off of, https://dev.to/aligoren/developing-an-express-application-using-typescript-3b1

The issue with the code is the in the controller files, I had

```
async GetUser(request: Request, response: Response) {
    let userId: string = request.params.id

    let user = await User.findOne({
        _id: userId,
    })

    response.send({
        user,
    })
}
```

Instead of:

```
GetUser = async (request: Request, response: Response) => {
    let userId: string = request.params.id

    let user = await User.findOne({
        _id: userId,
    })

    response.send({
        user,
    })
}
```

Another solution would of been to change:

```
switch (route.method) {
    case "get":
        this.router.get(path, this[route.function])
        break
    case "post":
        this.router.post(path, this[route.function])
        break
}
```

To:

```
switch (route.method) {
    case "get":
        this.router.get(path, this[route.function].bind(this))
        break
    case "post":
        this.router.post(path, this[route.function].bind(this))
        break
}
```

Just incase someone has a similar issue to me in the future.